# Using JavaScript, how can I display a set of questions on my quiz application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a quiz application using jQuery and JavaScript.

The application has next, previous and submit buttons.

Suppose I am on Q12 but want to immediately go to Q2, I have no provision for this sort and want to have this provision.

How do I display buttons for all questions and by clicking on that button would reach that particular question?

How can I use data-pages to do this?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Why not craft 12 buttons that take you to each of the questions individually? You could even trigger an independent function for each to start off with, and then refactor from there.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? :)

Comment: You can have buttons and then on button click fetch it from db and display it.

Comment: This is not a coding service, we help each other. To make it easier to help you show us your code, tell us what you have tried already, explain the error you are getting and tell us what you would like to happen.

Comment: This can be done in multiple ways, so needs to know your current implementations. How is your questions and answers stored? in Json?

Comment: Show us what you have so far and we can weigh in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be tons of solutions for this problem.

Assume you have 20 questions. Create 20 `div`s with style `display:none`. So these will be invisible. Let first `div`'s style as `display:block`. So it will be visible. Have a combobox with items Question 1, Question 2... Question 20. Listen changes on combobox so you will set `display:block` for selected question's `div` and `display:none` the older one.